# Laravel Filament Need to list table with same model with 2 different queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Laravel filament and resource have the same model and data is in two different tables as is_admin = 0 and is_admin = 1 and I need to list, how can I do this in the same user table with the filament.

I used custom page but I couldn't make tables and listings with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `getEloquentQuery` method inside of your resource. For instance:

```php
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->where('is_admin', 0);
}
```

This is a query builder interface, so you could join data to your query aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code

```
  public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
   {
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->where('is_admin', 0);
   }
```

was what I had been looking for